# Querying the Bazel cache?

Tags: bazel

I want to run e2e tests using Bazel.

Each Bazel e2e test rule requires a unique set of external services. For example, some e2e tests might require postgresql, others might require kafka, etc.

I don't want to stand up all these services before every single test run. Instead, I want to query the Bazel cache. If tests already passed and cached results remain valid, I would skip external service setup.

How can I query the Bazel cache to see which of my tests have already passed and won't rerun?

Comment: What about using aquery against the SkyFrame state? Could that do the trick? I have not used it but sounds like it could: https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/aquery.html#SkyFrame-state

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided you keep your Bazel server running, and don't change any dependencies (test files, source files, Bazel target configs), Bazel automatically caches passing tests.

In other words, if I run:

```
bazel test //foo:bar
```

The first time, bazel builds and executes the test. If I leave the Bazel server up and rerun

```
bazel test //foo:bar
```

...bazel returns rather quickly, and notes that you had a cache hit:

> //foo:bar (cached) PASSED in 0.1s

Please let me know if I've misunderstood your question.

Comment: Thanks for replying-- I'm looking for a way to query the Bazel cache itself. Following your example, how can I know whether `bazel test //foo:bar` will say `...(cached) PASSED...`? Without needing to run the `bazel test` command.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. And I'd say also something we would not want users to depend on. It's an implementation detail.

Comment: I'll mark this answer correct... on `bazel test` failure, I can stand up resources for the failed tests, then retry `bazel test`. Not ideal but good enough.

Comment: @hlopko querying the cache would be nice though. What makes you say it's an implementation detail? I thought caching was part of Bazel's core value?